# Html Table styles

Tags: html, css

Can any body point me to the links which has some table beautification code like the one mentioned and easy to implement

http://24ways.org/2005/tables-with-style

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery/ : )

Answer (score 1):

[Pattern Tap](http://www.patterntap.com) is a good recource for specific elements, there you can browse categories like tables, lists, tabs, backgrounds, and so on.